# Error in Zend Framework 2 MongoDB DoctrineMongoODMModule

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2

I am a newbie to MongoDb & Zend 2. I have downloaded vendor files from the following composer version.
    {
        "require": {
            "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*"
        }
    }

I have included the following Modules in application.config.php
DoctrineModule & DoctrineMongoODMModule.

But I am getting an error.
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\DoctrineModule\src\DoctrineModule\Module.php on line 54

Please advice me.

Comment: Could you paste your full composer file? You seem to be missing a lot of stuff

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have followed the steps in the URL.https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule. Could you please check the composer there? I hope your response will be helpful for me.

Comment: Can you confirm if composer actually installed  the `doctrine/common` package as a dependency of both ZF2 modules? If it was installed, this appears to be a problem with your autoloader. Composer should add any installed packages to its autoloader, which should then be included by your application as part of its own bootstrapping process.